# Getting a TypeError while running a websocket script in Python

Tags: python, websocket

I tried to establish a simple websocket connection through this code:

```
import websocket as ws

tiingo_key = #my respective API key
conn = ws.create_connection('wss://api.tiingo.com/crypto')
subscribe = {'eventName':'subscribe','authorization':tiingo_key,
             'eventData': {'thresholdLevel': 5}}
conn.send(subscribe)
conn.recv()
```

But I get the following error from line 7:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'dict' and 'bytes'
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to send a Python Dictionary object through an API. You need to look at the documentation for [tiingo](https://api.tiingo.com/documentation/crypto) and determine what sort of payload that API requires. It doesn't look like you can even call just the straight `/crypto` endpoint, but rather you need a further extension beyond that (something like `/crypto/top`. So figure out the endpoint you are trying to call, then base the subscribe payload around that. It shouldn't be a Python dictonary, but rather just a string, probably formatted in JSON. You could also use libraries like json to help.

I'd recommend reading up on how to call APIs so you can understand what the actual call to the API should be, then you just make Python code to create the needed payload.